# Power BI - How to apply steps to single table WITHOUT refreshing data source

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have read previous answers to this question and tried both methods suggested and it does not work for me.

**How can I "update" my report in PowerBI Desktop after adding a step to a query WITHOUT it automatically repeating EVERY STEP in the query including getting the source data again?**

Here is what happens:

1. My data source is a web api (example: https://interactleadforensics.com/ ... )
2. I transform my data and create a report. Everything is great.
3. I must make a small change to my query - for example, I replace a value in one column.
4. I hit "APPLY" so that my report can be updated with this one small change I made.
5. Instead of just applying the last step I made - the WHOLE thing is refreshed and my data set is RE-IMPORTED from fresh data.

I literally just want my report to use the OLD data and just add that one step I added in the query.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

*1. Right click on the Query and deselect "Include in Report Refresh"  [THIS DOES NOT WORK!]
2. Go to my OPTIONS and deselect "Allow table preview to download in the background" [THIS DOES NOT WORK]*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree this is very annoying. I also didnt find a solution by now, which works from the Power BI side.

What I do is, to filter the datta in the design phase to just a single month/week (not more than maybe 500 rows). This way changes happen really fast and when I am finished with the report I delte the filter. This saves so much time.